# Adding MIME Messages to a LinkedBlockingQueue Error

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime, pop3

Trying to add all MIME messages in a POP3 inbox to a LinkedBlockingQueue:

```
        inbox = pollStore.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

        for (int i = 0; i < inbox.getMessageCount(); i++) {
                Message messageI = inbox.getMessage(i+1);

                if (messageI != null ) {

                    MimeMessage mimeMessageI = (MimeMessage) messageI;

                    inboxQueue.add(mimeMessageI);

                    messageI.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
                }
        }
```

However I get java.lang.NullPointerException error upon running a tester class, which otherwise works. What could be the problem?

```
at com.tutorgami.relay.email.EmailFetchClient.poll(EmailFetchClient.java:147)
at com.tutorgami.relay.RelayIntegrationTest1.testSendingAndReceiving(RelayIntegrationTest1.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Where does the exception occur? Can you provide the stacktrace please?

Comment: Note that the Folder needs to remain open while the elements in the queue are processed.  The Message objects become invalid once the Folder is closed.  If you need copies of the messages that you can process offline, use the MimeMessage copy constructor.

Comment: That still doesn't work... what could possibly be wrong with adding a MimeMessage to a queue?!

Comment: The exception occurs on "inboxQueue.add(mimeMessageI);" line 147.